# what are main things are consider to Convert bootstrap application to angular

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I’m developing a website design using bootstrap now I want to move to convert my application as angular JS application.

What are the main things are consider converting angular application.

Comment: You will find your answer in this SO:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/15012542/1703503

Answer (score 0):

Angular is a JavaScript framework, Bootstrap is a CSS toolkit with some javascript modules for UI elements. They do different things.

You might want to look at [Angular UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) for a collection of directives from bootstrap but otherwise its just a matter of JS to Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap and Angular are different technologies with different purposes. I would advise you to start with Bootstrap and Angular documentations first.